# A JS fade effect doesn't work (for loop)

Tags: javascript, fade, effect

I tried doing a JS fade effect with the setTimeout() function and it appeared to work to some extent, but I can't seem to figure out what's wrong with the code below:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function FadeEffect(n)
{
    var i=1;
    fade = document.getElementById("box");
    if (n===1)
    {
        fade.style.opacity=i/10;
        i++;
        setTimeout("FadeEffect(1)",50);
        if (fade.style.opacity=1)
        {
         var i=1;
        }
    }
    else if (n===0)
    {
        fade.style.opacity=1-i/10;
        i++;
        setTimeout("FadeEffect(0)",50);
        if (fade.style.opacity=0)
        {
        var i=1;
        }
    }
}


</script>
<style type="text/css">
#box{
width: 200px;
height: 50px;
border: 1px solid black;
background-color: #ccc;
opacity: 0;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div onMouseOver="FadeEffect(1)" onMouseOut="FadeEffect(0)" id="box">Menu</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: updated the code with setTimeout() functions.

Comment: You could try jQuery. It's very nice and you can easily add fade-effects to elements.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the question is still not answered. See, I'm a beginner and I really want to figure it all out.

Comment: You say in your question that you use "setTimeout()" but there are no calls to "setTimeout()" in the code you posted.

Comment: Sorry, must have copy-pasted the wrong block of code. It's updated now.

Comment: Still some problems in your updated code. See my updated answer. By the way, the reason both Pointy and I used `Math.min()` and/or `Math.max()` in our answers is because of the way JavaScript handles floating point numbers (adding 0.1 ten times doesn't give 1.0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with the function that I can see.

First, your `if` statements both do an assignment rather than a comparison. You are saying `if (n=0)` (one =, assignment) when you should be saying `if (n===0)` (three ===, comparison, or you can use two == for a type-converting comparison).

Second, using a `for` loop to repeatedly change the style isn't going to fade because the browser doesn't update the display at the same time as your code is executing - essentially it uses the same thread for display and for JavaScript. So the page will be updated after the function exits. You need to give the browser a chance to update after each iteration by using `setTimeout()` - something like:

```
function fadeEffect(element,startValue,target,delay){
   element.style.opacity = startValue;
   if (startValue < target)
      startValue = Math.min(startValue + 0.1, target);
   else
      startValue = Math.max(startValue - 0.1, target);

   if (startValue != target)
      setTimeout(function(){fadeEffect(element,startValue,target,delay);}, delay);
}

<div onMouseOver="fadeEffect(this, 1, 0, 100);"
     onMouseOut="fadeEffect(this, 0, 1, 100);" id="box">Menu</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hLQ6y/2/

EDIT: Note that this code doesn't cope all that brilliantly if you move the mouse in and out too quickly, i.e., if you trigger the fade in before the fade out has finished. (You can see what I mean in my jsfiddle.) You can solve this by saving the return from [.setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) and calling [.clearTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearTimeout) if required. Given that I've already covered the essence of the question I'll leave the fine-tuning as an exercise for the reader...

UPDATE: Your updated code has introduced new if statements with the same assignment-instead-of-comparison problem. Also it is calling `setTimeout()` forever - you should do that conditionally as in the answers Pointy and I gave. Also you seem to be relying on the variable `i` which, as a local variable, will not retain its value between calls - you could make it a global, but better to manage it as a parameter like I did or as a local variable in an outer function like Pointy did.

Comment: Once again thanks for a detailed answer! I did some research and learned something new about operators and comparisons. I see my mistakes now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that all those changes to the style will happen before the browser bothers to update the display.  What you need to do is space out the changes over a much, much longer period of time using "setTimeout()".

```
function fadeIn() {
  function increment() {
    box.style.opacity = Math.min(1.0, (opacity += 0.1));
    if (opacity < 1.0) {
      setTimeout(increment, 100);
    }
  }
  var box = document.getElementById('box'), opacity = 0;
  box.style.opacity = opacity;
  setTimeout(increment, 100);
}
```

*edit* — [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/9z4YJ/) is a jsfiddle to demonstrate.

Comment: I've just edited the code with the setTimeout() function which doesn't appear to work.

Comment: I'm working on a jsfiddle but the site is really slow this morning ... hold on a sec

Comment: I see, however, could you please take a look at the code I've updated. It doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: I don''t see any updates to your code. Also make sure you read the answer from "nnnnn".

Comment: I've read the answers, but all I see is the same process written in another way. I would really like to figure out why my way is not the right way to do it.

Comment: Your way is wrong because web browsers simply do not work that way.  Changes to the "style" object of a DOM element are not put into effect absolutely immediately. Instead, the browser waits until the event causing your code to run (in your case, the mouse events) is completely finished.  Only then does it worry about screen updates, and it performs the update according to the final state of the "style".

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to fade, you need to create a function that sets the opacity -0.1 or +0.1 and then calls itself with setTimeout in 100ms (or fewer). If you don't let the script wait, it will be too fast and immediately set the opacity to 1.0.

Anyways, you could do this a lot easier using jQuery.